# Is it possible to toggle display of earned/unearned badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Every so often I like to take a break from answering question on SO so I'll visit the badges page and start putting in some effort towards the long-term grinds.  Things like [Marshal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/160/marshal) or [Proofreader](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/155/proofreader) are good examples.

I think it would be nice to have some sort of JavaScript buttons near the header of the page to toggle the display of: `All Badges | Earned Badges | Unearned Badges`.

If this has been discussed before I was unable to find it on meta.

**EDIT**: With the recent changes to the badge page which allows for filtering by type, hopefully this will have new interest.

Comment: How did you earn analytical?  I can't seem to trigger it.

Comment: @jjnguy I just got it on SF for clicking every link in the right panel and by visiting every question on meta.SF tagged FAQ.

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would be that hard to do.

Comment: @John - No I imagine it isn't. Earned badges are already identified in the DOM when the full page loads so that the check marks can be placed next to them. I was kind of hoping that a moderator would weight with philosophical reasons not to, or something along the lines of "not a priority at the moment".